# all of my listboxs are alawys on top

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have access 2007 form which contains some of the lists and one image that I used to re-size using on-click event but when it gets re-sized it becomes behind my lists even if I set the position property to "bring to front" and "send to back" for my lists and by the way it works well with text fields ; any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried Access 2013, but up until Access 2010 Listboxes and a few other elements do not support z-order positioning (behind or in front of other controls).   They are always on top.

In 2010 I use Layouts to expand / shrink the form as elements grow.   Another thing you could try is to put the image in a new form, and set the window border, title, etc to nothing.  Then you could open the image (as a form) and position it using DoCmd.MoveSize